# Asp.net control with custom event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, user-controls

I have a control that has a custom event.

Currently i define it like any other event

```
Public Event ContentChanged As EventHandler
```

But today i found a article they had a totally different way of handling it

```
Shared ReadOnly contentChangedKey As New Object()

Public Custom Event ContentChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Me.Events.AddHandler(contentChangedKey, value)
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Me.Events.RemoveHandler(contentChangedKey, Value)
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim contentChangedDelegate As EventHandler = _
            Me.Events(contentChangedKey)
        contentChangedDelegate(sender, e)
    End RaiseEvent 
End Event
```

The second way seems overly complicated what does it do that the first example doesn't??

Answer (score 1):

It has overcomplication :)

In other words you can add in there any other kind of processing that needs to be done when the envent happens or is bound to. Since you are controlling the actions taken when the event handler is added, removed or raised, you can do custom things.

For example say you had a control that had 5 buttons. One of the buttons however would be usless unless Event X was being handled.

With a custom event handler you could do this:

```
Public Custom Event ContentChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Me.Events.AddHandler(contentChangedKey, value)
        Me.SpecialButton.visible = true
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Me.Events.RemoveHandler(contentChangedKey, Value)
        Me.SpecialButton.visible = false 
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim contentChangedDelegate As EventHandler = _
            Me.Events(contentChangedKey)
        contentChangedDelegate(sender, e)
    End RaiseEvent 
End Event
```

if you did not have the custom event handler it would be very difficult to do this kind of logic. It all comes down to granularity; how much control do you need?

Of course you would need to be sure that when the `AddHandler` or `RemoveHandler` are being triggered that anything you expect to use in there is real. **This is an overly simplified example**

Comment: Ok, but does me.Events do any thing special? if im correct i could just use [Delegate].Combine and [Delegate].Remove and have a private EventHandler?

Comment: I have not had to work too much with delegates as event handlers but I did find [this article](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) which was very informative. Basically an event is a special delegate that has some benefits over a regular delegate. That article is C# but since it is all .NET the concepts are the same.